# How to change the weights of a deformer from a script in Maya?

Tags: python, maya, mel, pymel, maya-api

**How to change the weights of a deformer from a script in Maya?**

This question is ideally for `Pymel` in `Maya 2013`, but if it is not possible I would still be interested to know the answer in `Python`, `MEL`, or using the `C++ Maya-API`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for deformers, you can query weight in python as :

```
VertexNb = cmds.polyEvaluate(Mesh, v=1) - 1
weight = cmds.getAttr('{0}.weightList[0].weights[0:{1}]'.format(deformerNode, VertexNb))
```

for blendshape :

```
VertexNb = cmds.polyEvaluate(Mesh, v=1)
weight = cmds.getAttr('{0}.inputTarget[0].baseWeights[0:{1}]'.format(blendShapeNode, VertexNb))
```

To set value :

```
cmds.setAttr('{0}.weightList[0].weights[0:{1}]'.format(deformerNode, VertexNb), *weight, size=len(weight))
```

Comment: you may be tempted to use .weightList[0].weights[:] but maya do not return all the values everytime

Comment: I would like to verify your answer before I mark it as a solution, but I am puzzled by the `*` in `*weight`. What is its meaning in Python?

Comment: *weight is pythonic, it is used to unpack value.
as example, when you use :
def myFunc(*args), you see the same use of *, the
double star ** is used with kwargs (dictionnary)

Comment: It tested only the query of the weights so far. I would like to precise that the attribut `.weightList[0].weights` will return 1 for all indices which are not in the deformed set. We can have the indices of deformed vertices in Pymel using `.weightList[0].weights.getArrayIndices()`